# Does Java Based website / Application needs to be Multithreaded

Tags: java

I am a beginner to Java, My question is If I develop a Java Web Application (with Spring framework) , Does the Business Logic needs to be multithreded ? so that multiple people can hit the application at the same time?

Comment: Basically you should design your application to be multi threaded as the web application server threads the request already. But you should not create separate threads in your code (at least not as long as you don't know what you're doing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Servlet API, through which the web server calls your application, already handles requests from users using multiple threads. So a Java web application is already *by default multithreaded*.

Should also the *business logic* be multithreaded? In most situations, no. The recommendation is to make the business logic stateless, so that no mutable objects are shared between different requests. Otherwise you would need to deal with concurrency manually (because Java web apps are multithreaded), which is hard. The common solution is to share state only through a database and rely on the transaction isolation of the database to keep different requests from conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

The framework and the application servers already provide multithreading for you. There's no special steps needed to make it usable by several users at the same time.

Making a webapp so it would only be accessible to a single user at a time would require some work, and there's no reason why anyone would want that.

So there's nothing to be afraid here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, So when exactly anyone will use multithreading?

Comment: In a web application or in general? In a web application one wouldn't generally even try to add multithreading code, due to the nature of webapps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the kind of business logic that you want to execute.  If you have to do some asynchronous actions in your business processing that should not block the user, then you most likely will need to spawn worker threads that handle your processing while the user continues to use your application.
If it is feasable to let the user wait / block interaction untill the business logic has been processed, then there is no need of extra multi-threading in your application.

Note that multi threading implementation is often a tedious job and underestimated.  It needs good knowledge on thread safety of third party frameworks which you might be using and can result in non obvious errors.